# Error: Unknown rule type username in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ant-design-pro

I am new to ReactJs, I am Using `Ant-design` For Registration Form and applied some validation Rules. I want to validate User when user enter something in fields, message `( Username must be Unique )` is shown to the user for guidance . But when I enter something Error is occur `Unknown rule type username`.

**Code of Form**

```
              <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('username', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    type: 'username',
                    message: 'Username Must be Unique!',
                  },
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please Enter Your Username',
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Username" />)}
              </FormItem>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must be confusing `type` with something else.

According to this page: https://ant.design/components/form/ , type will rather be referenced to something like `string` or `boolean`.

**EDIT:**

```
    ...
    {
        type: string,
            message: 'Username Must be a string',
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Could you please add a code that validate my form with string or boolean

Comment: I think you do not fully understand the `type:` rule. The string indicates that it expects characters like letters (a b c), numbers(1 2 3) and symbols (! @ #). The logic for a unique username has to be developed outside of this.